# What references do I need on my web page to use Java and ASP.NET?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

I have created a blank aspx page in SPD2010 and I want to add a series of asp.net buttons that launch forms and other pages in modals when clicked.

The issue is that the buttons only work if I embed them on a page based from my main master page so I assume my blank aspx page requires some references.

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Open" runat="server" OnClientClick="var options = {url: 'https://WebAddress/siteforms/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=8&ListId={219B4A5B-9750-4A42-BC3D-4C97BD594806}&RootFolder=', title: 'Amend};SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);return false;"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of modal dialogs are you using? SharePoint is based on asp.net, so you would need to use only asp.net specially with old versions of SharePoint. Can I know why would you want to use server side controls to manage modal dialogs? You can do that easily with JS, and it's going to work with newer releases of SharePoint.

Comment: Mohammed, I wish to have a blank page with several buttons in a simple HTML table, the buttons will launch my sharepoint forms in modals. If there is a way to do this without the server side controls then please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: Hi @JazzyN, you can have have all that in an HTML design, without any server side control. But first, which SharePoint forms do you need to open?

Comment: Just some Nintex forms

Answer (score 2):

To Open the SharePoint Modal dialog in the custom aspx page the following references need to be added.

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="init.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink2" Name="sp.init.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink3" Name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink4" Name="sp.core.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink5" Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink7" Name="sp.ui.dialog.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
```

and register the SharePoint.WebControls using below tag in the page

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

and please make sure that you've added reference to the MicorsoftAjax.js library in the page to avoid issue with recognizing type of SharePoint ScriptLink

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I now get this error when I load a page after using the above references:     


Error 

An error occurred during the processing of /sites/SitePages/untitled.aspx. Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

Comment: Just figured out I need t amend the web.config file to bypass the code block. Is there another way?